# Angular.js How to update the scope from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I update scope in directive?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p t></p>
</div>
```

My directive:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('t', function () {
        return {
            template: '{{text}}',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.text = '1';
                element.click(function() {
                     scope.text = '2';
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);
```

After click directive does not update.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) method:

```
  element.click(function() {
      scope.$apply(function(){
           scope.text = '2';
      });
  });
```

Explanation: [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933)