# Updating Scope from a Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have defined a scope in my directive.

```
scope.selection = 3
```

When I apply the directive to an element,

```
<div myDirective></div>
```

its template would print the scope var correctly.

```
<span>{{selection}}</span> //prints: 3
```

but when I update the scope variable in the directive it does not update in the view.

```
element.bind("keydown", function(event){
    if(event.which === 38){ //up arrow
        scope.selection--;
        console.log(scope.selection); //logs the updated value but view stays the same
    }
}
```

Can I bind scopes from a directive?

EDIT:

If I view a different browser tab then go back to the app the view is then updated.

Comment: you need to call `scope.$apply()`, see http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: You need to do `$scope.$digest()`; `$scope.$apply()` would also work, but it unnecessarily starts a digest from `$rootScope`

Comment: Ok thanks guys both of those work, I thought as a keypress event was firing this would not be needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js How update scope in directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154539/angular-js-how-update-scope-in-directive)